# Linq.Dyanmic GroupJoin implementation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects, dynamic-linq

I am working on creating an Extension Method in the Linq.Dynamic project for GroupJoin. But, for some reason it will not run. The signatures seem to match.

```
public static IQueryable GroupJoin(this IQueryable outer, IEnumerable inner, string outerSelector, string innerSelector, string resultsSelector, params object[] values)
{
    if (inner == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("inner");
    if (outerSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("outerSelector");
    if (innerSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("innerSelector");
    if (resultsSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultsSelctor");

    LambdaExpression outerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(outer.ElementType, null, outerSelector, values);
    Type enumType = GetList(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType).GetType();

    LambdaExpression innerSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, null, innerSelector, values);

    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] { 
    Expression.Parameter(outer.ElementType, "outer"), Expression.Parameter(enumType, "inner") };
    LambdaExpression resultsSelectorLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(parameters, null, resultsSelector, values);        

    return outer.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "GroupJoin",
            new Type[] { outer.ElementType, inner.AsQueryable().ElementType, outerSelectorLambda.Body.Type, resultsSelectorLambda.Body.Type },
            outer.Expression, inner.AsQueryable().Expression, Expression.Quote(outerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(innerSelectorLambda), Expression.Quote(resultsSelectorLambda)));
}

public static IEnumerable GetList(System.Type type)
{
    return (IEnumerable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
}
```

This code gives me the following error:

> No generic method 'GroupJoin' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

In looking at the results of each piece they seem to match:
Writing the follwing GroupJoin:

```
man.Contacts.GroupJoin(man.ContactAddresses, param_0 => param_0.ContactId, param_0 => param_0.ContactId, 
                (outer, inner) => new { ContactId = outer.ContactId, FirstName = outer.FirstName, LastName = outer.LastName, MI = outer.MiddleInitial, ContactAddresses = inner });
```

I get the debug of:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.GroupJoin(
.Constant<IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryProxy`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact]>(IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryProxy`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact]),    .Constant<IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryProxy`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress]>(IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryProxy`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress]),
'(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Int64]>),
'(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress,System.Int64]>),
'(.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`3[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress],    <>f__AnonymousType0`5[System.Int64,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress]]]>))
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Int64]>(LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact $param_0)
{
    $param_0.ContactId
}    
.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress,System.Int64]>(LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress $param_0)
{
    $param_0.ContactId
}    
.Lambda 
    #Lambda3<System.Func`3
    [
        LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress],
        <>f__AnonymousType0`5
        [
            System.Int64,System.String,System.String,System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
            [
                LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress
            ]
        ]
    ]>
    (LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact $outer, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
        [LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress] $inner) 

    {
    .New <>f__AnonymousType0`5[System.Int64,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress]](
        $outer.ContactId,
        $outer.FirstName,
        $outer.LastName,
        $outer.MiddleInitial,
        $inner)
}
```

With the following GroupJoin:

```
man.Contacts.GroupJoin(man.ContactAddresses, "ContactId", "ContactId", "new (outer.ContactId as ContactId, outer.FirstName as FirstName, outer.LastName as LastName, outer.MiddleInitial as MI, inner as ContactAddresses)");
```

Then looking at the debug:

```
.Call GroupJoin (
{value(IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryProxy'1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact])},    {value(IdeaBlade.EntityModel.EntityQueryProxy'1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress])},
'(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func'2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Int64]>),
'(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func'2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress,System.Int64]>),
'(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func'3[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress],DynamicClass1]>)

//ContactId
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func'2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Int64]>(LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact $var1) 
{
    $var1.ContactId
}

//CA.ContactId
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func'2[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress,System.Int64]>(LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress $var1)
{
    $var1.ContactId
}
//Dynamic Result
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`3[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress],DynamicClass1]>(
    LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.Contact $outer,
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LOC.AMP.Data.DomainModel.ContactAddress] $inner)
    {
    .New DynamicClass1(){
        ContactId = $outer.ContactId,
        FirstName = $outer.FirstName,
        LastName = $outer.LastName,
        MI = $outer.MiddleInitial,
        ContactAddresses = $inner
    }
}
```

The only thing different is `List<T>` compared to IEnumerable. But `List<T>` is IEnumerable.
The error reads like the signature is wrong. I just can't figure it out.

Any incite would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

```
man.Contacts.GroupJoin
```

What is the Type of `Contacts`? Does it inherit from `IQueryable`? or `IQueryable<T>`?

My guess is it is an `IQueryable<T>`. This error:

> No generic method 'GroupJoin' on type
>   'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible
>   with the supplied type arguments and
>   arguments. No type arguments should be
>   provided if the method is non-generic.

Is saying that there are type arguments being provided in the method call, and it can't find a generic method 'GroupJoin' that is compatible with these type arguments. The 'GroupJoin' that you wrote is expecting **no** type arguments, so you will probably have to modify it to expect one or some.

I think it is also possible that the problem is with the second parameter, where  `man.ContactAddresses` is passed in. But `Contacts` is the first place I'd look.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be too late but I found this as answer:

Try using:

```
Type enumType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(inner.AsQueryable().ElementType);
```

It worked for me.